# Conditional formatting depending on the extreme values of each row

Tags: google-sheets, rows, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying conditionally to format a Google Sheets sheet with 1,000 or more rows. I have to colour it depending of the highest and lowest value of each row.

[image: Example image]
(Red=highest,green=lowest) I want to make the second example without having to write every row B1:F1,B2:B2, etc, because it is a large document.

Answer (score 1):

In conditional formatting, you need to select B7:F9 and add a custom formula

```
=rank(B7,$B7:$F7,true)=1
```

then choose dark green fill colour.

Then add another rule

```
=rank(B7,$B7:$F7,true)=2
```

and choose light green fill colour.

Then repeat until you have a rule for each of the five colours.

Comment: Thank you. So it couldn't be done with gradient color (I've puted 5 columns but it has more and values could be higher and lower than showed)